# Is there a sequence whose set of subsequence limits is $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is there a sequence whose set of subsequential limits are $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$?

I was told that there wasn't such a sequence, is this true?

Comment: What do you know about the set of subsequential limits of a sequence $(a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N}$?

Comment: @t.b. Can you provide a little more please?

Comment: Okay, I'd say there isn't such a sequence if $Q\cap[0,1]$ are taken to be exclusive (e.g. the only possible subsequence limits). Assume that $a_n$ fulfills this property, and let $b_n$ be a sequence of rational numbers in $[0,1]$ whose limit is an irrational number in $[0,1]$. For each $b_i$ we can find infinite members of $a_n$ that're close to $b_i$ as much as we like, so we can create a subsequence of $a_n$ whose limit is $b_i$'s limit. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct -- you could write that up as an answer.

Comment: @joriki I had to wait 8 hours (!) before I could type it up, so I selected Kannappan's answer instead :).

Comment: It may not be directly useful to you, but the topological argument is that the set of limit points is closed, since the closure of the rationals in $[0,1]$ is $[0,1]$ if a sequence approaches all the rationals it must approach any other point in the interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have been told the right answer, if you want $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ to be the exclusive limit points!

As t.b. points out, the set of subsequential limits, $\mathcal{S}$ is a closed set. In the 'epsilonics', it would mean, 
 Whenever $x \in \mathcal S^c$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that, $B_\delta(x) \subseteq \mathcal{S}^c$, where $ \mathcal{S}^c$ stands for complement of $\mathcal {S}$. A special thanks to @joriki, (also @t.b.) in this connection!! (Read the comments, in case you are wondering why.)

But as irrational numbers are dense in $[0,1]$, there does not exist any open ball $B_\delta(x)$ with property as mentioned.

Comment: What's $E$? I think it should say "whenever $x\in\overline{\mathcal{S}}$, there is $\delta\gt0$ such that $B_\delta(x)\subset\overline{\mathcal{S}}$?

Comment: @joriki Fixed, Thanks for the pointer. But, I would keep it $\mathcal{S}$, because $\mathcal{S}$ is a closed set, and will coincide with its closure, $\bar{\mathcal{S}}$.

Comment: Sorry, I should have defined my notation -- that was supposed to be the complement, not the closure. What you've written is the definition of $\mathcal S$ being open rather than closed. (BTW you can get the bar to cover the entire $\mathcal S$ by using `\overline` instead of `\bar`.)

Comment: @joriki I probably must have gone completely off my brains. I'll fix it. Thanks for your LaTeX help in this direction.

Comment: Using $\overline{\mathcal{S}}$ for the *complement* of $\mathcal{S}$ is a rather unfortunate decision. In standard topological notation $\overline{\mathcal S}$ stands for the *closure* of a set. I suggest to use $\mathcal{S}^c$ or simply $[0,1] \smallsetminus \mathcal{S}$.

Comment: @t.b. I agree with you and that's the way I'll understand too, see my previous comments for a glimpse. But that I've explained the notation, I don't see a need to edit. If you feel really needed, please feel free to edit it.

Comment: @Kannapan: I don't see the *need* to edit it but using standard notation in a non-standard way is a very bad idea, even if it's explained. (By the way: given that you're so eager to edit so many things so often elsewhere, I'm a bit surprised by this statement...)

Comment: @t.b. I was a little tired, editing this post several time before you pointed this out. I will edit it now. And, as for editing other posts, I feel that helps stack exchange users get to the question right away if there are no errors. So, if that's not so, I'll stop editing posts too often.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\alpha$ be your favourite irrational number in the interval $[0,1]$. For definiteness, let $\alpha=\sqrt{2}/2$.
Suppose that the set of subsequential limits of the sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$
**includes** all rationals in the interval $[0,1]$.  We will show that $\alpha$ is also a subsequential limit of the sequence $(a_n)$.

The rationals are dense in the reals. So there is a sequence $r_1,r_2,r_3,\dots$ of rationals in $[0,1]$ such that $(r_n)$ has limit $\alpha$. Such a sequence, can, for example, be obtained by truncating the decimal expansion of $\alpha$ further and further along.

We now construct our subsequence of $(a_n)$ that has limit $\alpha$.
Let $n_1$ be the smallest index $i$ such that $|a_i-r_1|<\frac{1}{2}$.  There is such an $i$ because the sequence $(a_n)$ has, by assumption, a subsequence that converges to $r_1$.

Let $n_2$ be the smallest index $i$ such that $i>n_1$, and  $|a_i-r_2|<\frac{1}{2^2}$.  There is such an $i$ because $(a_n)$ has a subsequence that converges to $r_2$.

Let $n_3$ be the smallest index $i$ such that $i>n_2$, and  $|a_i-r_3|<\frac{1}{2^3}$.  There is such an $i$ because $(a_n)$ has a subsequence that converges to $r_3$.

Continue in the obvious way. The sequence $(a_{n_k})$ is a subsequence of $(a_n)$ and converges to $\alpha$.

**Comment:** We have proved that *every* real number in $[0,1]$ is a subsequential limit of $(a_n)$. More generally, let $(a_n)$ be *any* sequence. The same argument shows that the set of subsequential limits of $(a_n)$ is closed.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\{a_j\}_{j=0}^{\infty}$ is a sequence that has $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ as limit points. Let $\alpha$ be an irrational number in $[0,1]$ and let $\{b_j\}_{j=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of rationals in $[0,1]$ that converges to $\alpha$.  Set $d_i = |\alpha-b_i|$; by construction $d_i\rightarrow 0$.  Since there is a subsequence of $\{a_i\}_{i=0}^{\infty}$ converging to $b_i$ there must be some $a_i$ within $d_i$ of $b_i$.  Thus $a_i$ is within $2d_i$ of $\alpha$.  Doing this for every $i$ yields a subsequence of $\{a_j\}_{j=0}^{\infty}$ converging to $\alpha$.

Consequently, any sequence that has $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ as limit points (and I make no claims about the existence of such a sequence) actually has all of $[0,1]$ as limit points.

Comment: Such sequences (having subsequences that converge to every point in $[0,1]$) do exist: one example is the [van der Corput sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Corput_sequence), obtained by reversing the base-$n$ representation of consecutive integers.